# How do I test the Bitcoin alert message?

Tags: alert, bitcoin

I am developing a Bitcoin client and I want to test my code by receiving the "alert" Bitcoin message. But I don't know how to solicit this message from another node on the Bitcoin network. From reading the protocol specs (below) it sounds like this message is only sent in response to some malicious event, which I probably don't want to try and emulate (I don't want to get myself blacklisted on Testnet :)

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#alert

Comment: This is probably a question for bitcoin stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

### Overview

1. Clone bitcoin
2. Add sendalert.cpp
3. Patch the alert functions
4. Patch the Makefile and init.cpp
5. Build the binary
6. Run the binary in two different places that connect to each other.
7. Wait.

### Clone bitcoin

The very first thing you'll need to do is to fork the [bitcoin][bitcoinrepo] repository. On github, you can just click "Fork" or you can clone the repository and make all the changes locally. Either way, you're going to need your own copy of the bitcoin source code.

### Add sendalert.cpp

This is a modified version of the gist found [here][sendalert]. You will need to put [this file][modsendalert] into the [src directory][bitcoinsrc].

Optionally, you can edit the actual alert properties like the comment text, status bar text, what alerts to actually now ignore, etc. You can see the full alert specification [here][alertspecification].

### Patch the alert functions

In [src/alert.cpp][alertcpp], make these functions return true:

- `IsInEffect`
- `AppliesToMe`
- `CheckSignature`

### Patch the Makefile and init.cpp

Near the top of [init.cpp][initcpp], you need to put this code:

`extern void ThreadSendAlert();`

Near the end of the file right before:

`return !fRequestShutdown;`

put in this line:

`threadGroup.create_thread(boost::bind(ThreadSendAlert));`

You also need to add sendalert.cpp into [Makefile.am][makefile] by adding sendalert.cpp to the list of libbitcoin_server_a_SOURCES. This can be done after this line:

`txmempool.cpp \`

and adding this line after:

`sendalert.cpp \`

### Build the binary

Follow the instructions for [unix][buildinstructions] or [mac][buildinstructionsmac].

### Run the binary in two different places

You'll need two machines, though it may be possible to do with just one using different ports, I haven't been able to figure this out. You will need the ip addresses of each machine. Say you have machine A and B. You want machine B to receive an alert.

From machine A you'll need to run:

`./bitcoind -printtoconsole -sendalert -testnet -addnode=<ip of machine B>`

From machine B you'll need to run:

`./bitcoind -printtoconsole -sendalert -testnet -addnode=<ip of machine A>`

Make sure they're started relatively closely (within 5 seconds of each other).

### Wait

About 1 minute after you start, you should see an alert in the console of machine B that looks like this:

`ThreadSendAlert:
hash=14c7c1217b54b953a81b08e0be16b9a56a9365240169d808424d5e7dd5690769
vchMsg=010000003271cd5400000000c2ffdb5400000000150400002a000000021004000012040000721101007311010002102f5361746f7368693a302e31302e302f0f2f5361746f7368693a302e392e332f88130000177465737420636f6d6d656e742031343232373530303032165445535420414c4552543a203134323337303430303210746573742072657365727665642e2e2e
vchSig=304402204cf39bec79eb10ad056f7a1ca48cfda3d612444a22eead543f345ae5f9c483df02204fc13370a17c639b796061ed39f294dd145363b3b953b9b4475da3b40bcd3f0e
ThreadSendAlert() : Sending alert
attempting relay
ThreadSendAlert() : Sent alert to x.x.x.x:18333
attempting relay
ThreadSendAlert() : Sent alert to x.x.x.x:18333
attempting relay
ThreadSendAlert() : Sent alert to x.x.x.x:18333
attempting relay
ThreadSendAlert() : Sent alert to x.x.x.x:18333
attempting relay
ThreadSendAlert() : Sent alert to x.x.x.x:18333
ThreadSendAlert() : Alert sent to 5 nodes`

Complete instructions here: https://gist.github.com/jimmysong/4c72d098255b217b4c8c